# Reflection in a cylindrical mirror

Tags: reflection, geometric-optics

Suppose I have a completely cylindrical surface which is silvered on the inside. I want to know what type of reflection takes place when an object is placed inside the ring.

Does infinite reflections take place like in the case of two parallel mirrors? If it does take place, since the reflections are formed on concentric circles whose radius gets bigger, does magnification take place?

Finally, what will happen to the image(s) when the object is placed away from the center of the cylinder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends entirely on the size of the object, and its location. Light that emanates from the axis will be reflected back to the axis - but if it starts out not normal to the axis, it will return at a different point along the axis. Light that starts out off-axis will be reflected at constant angle, and continue to pass at a certain distance from the axis on each subsequent reflection.

[image]

It's definitely more complex than two parallel mirrors.

Comment: will infinite images be formed like in the case of two parallel mirrors, that is, will concentric rings of images be formed?

Comment: @Ashkit: Each reflexion in Floris's drawing begets an chord such that the chord - surface system is isometrically (rotationally) congruent to the foregoing reflexion: each chord and its forerunner are reflexionally similar about the normal to the circle at the point of reflexion. So the incidence point on the circle advances a constant angle (subtended at the circle's center) - say $\alpha$ each "bounce" and you can choose this angle to be anything you wish by appropriate aiming. Therefore: the loop will close if and only if there are integers $m>0,\,n>0 \ni m\,\alpha = 2\,n\,\pi$ ...

Comment: @Akshit .... *i.e.* $m$ bounces equals $n$ full cycles. So the path will close if and only if $\alpha$ is a rational multiple of $2\,\pi$. As for image forming: this device will scramble even point sources, by the above discussion: some rays will form closed loops with regular, course spacing, others with fine spacing, others won't close at all. Images will be scrambled into a complicated set of caustics.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance well said!